# How to create a sprite class to prevent repeating the same code all the time?

Tags: c#, class, xna

I'm using XNA to create a Space Invaders copy. So I'm animating many sprites with the same logic placed in their own class, but using different values for most vars. Here is my way of animating from spritesheets:

```
Texture2D playerTex;
Vector2 playerPos = new Vector2(x, y), playerOrigin;
Rectangle playerHitBox;
float animationTimer = 0f, animationInterval = 100f;
int currentFrame = 1, frameWidth = example number, frameHeight = example number 2;

public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
{
    playerTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship");
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    playerHitBox = new Rectangle(currentFrame * frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    playerOrigin = new Vector2(playerHitBox.X / 2, playerHitBox.Y / 2);
    animationTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
    if (animationTimer > animationInterval)
    {
        currentFrame++;
        animationTimer = 0f;
    }

    if (currentFrame == 2)
    {
        currentFrame = 0;
    }
    playerHitBox = new Rectangle(currentFrame * frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    playerOrigin = new Vector2(playerHitBox.Width / 2, playerHitBox.Height / 2);
}

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(playerTex, playerPos, playerHitBox, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
}
```

Instead of using this logic for every animating object within its own class I'm looking for a way to create a sprite class anduse inheritance to `Update()`/`Draw()` the sprite. Could something like this be a good approach for the `Draw()` method?

```
    public void Draw(Texture2D spriteTex, Vector2 spritePos, Nullable<Rectangle> spriteSourceRect, Color spriteColor, Single spriteRotation, Vector2 spriteOrigin, Vector2 spriteScale, SpriteEffects spriteEffects, Single spriteLayerDepth, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if (spriteTex != null)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(spriteTex, spritePos, spriteSourceRect, spriteColor, spriteRotation, spriteOrigin, spriteScale, spriteEffects, spriteLayerDepth);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creating a class for sprites can be a good idea, and in most cases it is. However, your `Draw` method seems to take too many parameters. Most of them could be instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Create Sprite class to keep common animation properties like texture, duration and current index.
2. Create Invider class for custom data like position, health and other.
3. Create a collection to store custom data for each object in game class.

For example:

```
class Sprite
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Rectangle Frame;
    private frameIndex;
    private frameCount;
    private frameDuration;
    private frameInterval;

    public Sprite(Texture pTexture, ...)
    {
        // init sprite data
    }
    public Update(GameTime pGameTime)
    {
        // update sprite data
    }
}

class Invider
{
    private Sprite Sprite;
    public Vector2 Porision;
    public int Health;

    public Invider(Sprite pSprite, Vector2 pPosition)
    {
        this.Sprite = pSprite;
        this.Position = pPosition;
    }
    public void Update(GameTime pGameTime)
    {
        // update invider data
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch pSpriteBatch)
    {
        pSpriteBatch.Draw(this.Sprite.Texture, this.Sprite.Frame, this.Position, Color.White);
    }
}

public class Game1 : Game
{
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private Dictionary<int, Invider> invidersByID;
    private Sprite inviderSprite;

    public override Initialize()
    {
        // fill inviderByID collection
    }

    public override LoadData()
    {
        // create inviderSprite
    }

    public static UpdateStatic(GameTime pGameTime)
    {
        // update static data like frame index
    }
    public override void Update(GameTime pGameTime)
    {
        this.inviderSprite.Update(pGameTime);

        foreach(Invider invider in invidersByID.Values){
        {
            invider.Update(pGameTime);
        }
    }
    public override Draw(SpriteBatch pSpriteBatch)
    {
        this.spriteBatch.Begin();
        foreach(Invider invider in invidersByID.Values){
        {
            invider.Update(pGameTime);
        }
        this.spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```